# Settimer is calling only once after delay, But, It is not repeatedly calling in React Native

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, timer, timeout

I have to call some API for every 10 minutes in my react native application. So, I have defined timer in ComponentDidMount method along with Setinterval, But, It is calling only once, It is not calling repeatedly.

```
  componentDidMount() {
this.timer = setInterval(() => this.callAPI(), 600000); 
  }

callApi = async () => {
//calling some api here

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to console log in callApi method it works

Comment: It is calling once, Later it is not gets called.

Comment: You set 600000 Interval so It will called on every 10 minutes

Comment: Yes, But, It is calling first time after 10 minutes, Later its not calling again and again even 1 hour also. I mean it is not repeating.

Comment: Can you check if your component gets unmounted during the waiting period? That's probably why it does not fire again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue by following.

```
setInterval(() => this. callAPI(), 600000);
```

The above method calling every 10 minutes delay.
Hope this will help someone in future.